# Having relationship between tables to update details

Tags: java, jdbc

I have two tables i.e. USR_TABLE and USR_PROFILE.

The USR_TBALE have this columns:

1. ID (Primary key)
2. full name
3. email
4. user staus
5. password

And inside user profile table:

1. ID (Foreign key referencing user table) and also as Primary key
2. User_status
3. company
4. role

Inside user table, I am programmatically inserting userId (using Java UUID), full name, email, user_status and password.

My question is when I insert ID into USR_TABLE, do I have to automatically insert the same ID in USR_PROFILE table to keep the ID values same?

If so how do I do that in java?

Right now my code is:

Registration DAO:

```
public class RegistrationDAO {

    public int insert(UserProfile user) {

        int count  = 0;
        try {            
            String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            Connection con = DBConnection.getConnection();
            String query = "insert into TBL_USER (USR_ID, USR_FULL_NAME,USR_PRIMARY_EMAIL,USR_PASSWORD,USR_STATUS) values(?,?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query);

            pst.setString(1, uniqueID);
            pst.setString(2, user.getFullName());
            pst.setString(3, user.getEmail());
            pst.setString(4, user.getPassword());
            pst.setString(5, "PENDING");
            count  = pst.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("@@@@Record insertion error in Registration DAO@@@@");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Profile DAO:

```
public class ProfileDAO {

    public void SaveProfile(UserProfile userProfile) {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            con = DBConnection.getConnection();
            String query = "Insert into TBL_USER_PROFILE (USR_SUMMARY, USR_ROLE, USR_COMPANY, USR_FROM, USR_TO, USR_LOCATION) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
            pst.setString(1, userProfile.getSummary());
            pst.setString(2, userProfile.getRole());
            pst.setString(3, userProfile.getCompany());
            pst.setString(4, userProfile.getFrom());
            pst.setString(5, userProfile.getTo());
            pst.setString(6, userProfile.getLocation());
            pst.executeUpdate();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error in Profile DAO class in method SaveProfile()");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes - those values need to match.  are you saying you change the primary key userID after the fact? that is a bad idea...

Comment: @Randy I didn't understand what you meant by "are you saying you change the primary key userID after the fact?"